# Building an audioplayer in vue; how to get the audio to begin playing after changing a bound :src?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html5-audio

**Example of issue:**
https://jsfiddle.net/manfrin/tnszqwpd/58/ (Warning, will start playing music on load).

I have an audio tag that looks like

```
  <audio 
    :src="current" 
    @timeupdate="time = $event.target.currentTime" 
    ref="audio" 
    @ended="nextTrack()" 
    autoload preload="auto" autoplay>
  </audio>
```

When a track ends, it calls `nextTrack` which changes the src, like so:

```
nextTrack: function () {
    if (this.playlist.length > 0) {
    this.current = this.playlist.shift()
    this.$refs.audio.load()
    this.$refs.audio.play()
    this.playing = true
  } else {
    this.current = "";
    this.playing = false;
  }
},
```

When there are tracks in the playlist, it works fine -- `this.current` is set to the next track and it begins to play fine.

However, if you clear out the playlist first (press the 'Next Track' button when the playlist is empty) and then add a track and press play, the track does not begin. I call `play()` on the audio tag and it still does not play.

I believe it might be because I am calling `this.$refs.audio.play()` right after setting `this.current`, so perhaps vue has not updated the `:src` in time for the `play()` to be called on the correct src, but I tried a `setTimeout` and it did not fix it. Additionally, I think `nextTrack` works when there is a playlist because `autoplay` is set, not because I am calling load/play.

How can I both change an audio tag's `src` and cause it to play in the same sequence?

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with this for a couple days, and I finally decided to post a StackOverflow question and of course 5 minutes later I figure it out.

Since I need to depend on the state I'm setting in my `nextTrack()` method, I can use `this.$nextTick`. My nextTrack/play look like this:

```
  nextTrack: function () {
    if (this.playlist.length > 0) {
    this.current = this.playlist.shift()
    this.playing = true
    this.play()
  } else {
    this.current = "";
    this.playing = false;
  }
},
play: function () {
    if (!this.playing) {
    if (!this.current && this.playlist.length > 0) {
      this.$refs.audio.pause()
      this.current = this.playlist.shift()
    }
    if (!this.current) {
      this.playing = false
    } else {
      this.playing = true
    }
    this.$nextTick(() => {
        if (this.playing) {
        this.$refs.audio.play()
      }
    })
  } else {
    this.$refs.audio.pause()
    this.playing = false
  }
},
```

With the important part being this, specifically:

```
    this.$nextTick(() => {
        if (this.playing) {
        this.$refs.audio.play()
      }
    })
```

`nextTick` allows me to wait until vue has handled the state updates, and from there I can call play on the audio ref.

Working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/manfrin/tnszqwpd/72/ (Again, audio autoplay warning).